# How to get value of input on onChange() event in Amplify studio?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I need to create a input field which takes a value from user and show it in a textbox, I have used Amplify studio to generate reactjs component from Figma. I have added child property and added a `onChange` event on the input.

My issue is I need to display the value which is entered by the user in place of "Your name is" text by using the child property option in reactjs.

Is it possible to do this using amplify studio "UI event handler"?

This is what I have tried,

The following component works, but it will just show "Your name" as the value is hardcoded

[image: This is what I have tried]

[I have checked this documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/console/uibuilder/eventhandling/)

Comment: Please sure any code you've written for it already

Comment: @neilge App contains only the above component no other code, I want to generate the logic in amplify studio using event handling.